# How to get ARM 64 for API 30 and 29 in Android Emulator on MacBook M1?

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, arm64, apple-m1

I cannot see ARM 64 for Android 10 & 9 in the SDK Manager on MacBook M1. I have reinstalled AS (Arctic Fox), cleaned all previous data and it didn't help.
Do you know what to do in this case? I know that other people are able to create Android Emulator on M1 with API 30 and 29.
[SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dugS.png)

Answer (score 2):

If anyone will be struggling with similar issue, the solution is to add manually proper Android System Image to the *system-images/android-30/google_apis* folder. You can download it and follow the steps like it is described [here](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sysimg-google-arm-v8a-download.html)